# Too many redirects in codeigniter 3 authenticate hook

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have this as a hook to get user session to all CI controllers, but when I enter into login page I will get net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. This is my script:

```
<?php class Authenticate{
  protected $CI;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->CI = & get_instance();

  }
  public function check_user_login(){
      if(!$this->CI->session->is_logged_in){
          redirect('main/login');    
      } 
      }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the function isn't called while the user is in 'main/login', otherwise it will be recursive and you'll get too many redirects.